# Is it possible to obtain the spoken language from youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-dl

I'm using youtube-dl to download videos from youtube that we query using words from a target foreign language, but there's no guarantee that the video is in the target language. Is there any way to know what is the spoken language in a video when using youtube-dl? I figure youtube must know this info since it generates captions for some videos. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can use youtube-dl to get the video language, but if you use the Youtube Data API it is possible.

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) shows that you can get the video language in multiple ways:

- Video title / description language: `snippet.defaultLanguage`
- spoken language in default audio track: `snippet.defaultAudioLanguage`

The option for you would be to call the Youtube Data API and check if `snippet.defaultAudioLanguage` matches your desired language.

Comment: It seems to be missing now, in the doc you link there is no `snippet.defaultLanguage` value anymore.

Comment: @fedorqui I just looked in the documentation on my link. `snippet.defautlLanguage` aswell as `snippet.defaultAudioLanguage` are both still documented. Maybe you just missed them?

Comment: It is quite strange because I cannot find any `defaultLanguage` or `defaultAudioLanguage` text in the whole page https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Comment: It is strange indeed. so you can't see [this](https://puu.sh/CjEIg/e076d2adc1.png) or [this](https://puu.sh/CjEJt/1c3350fa3f.png) anywhere on the page? For me it's under `Properties`

Comment: oh now I see them! The difference being I changed the language of my laptop from Spanish to English, so now youtube displays me the site in English. Many many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with bash like this:

`yt-dlp --dump-json $1 | jq --raw-output ".language"`

where $1 is the YouTube short code.